# The proof of adding edges without improving algebraic connectivity $\lambda_2$ of graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I am reading the following paper:

"Y. Fan, On Spectral Integral Variations of Graphs", in particular, the following part:

[image]

I am confused about the following part:

If $\lambda_2(G) = \lambda_2(G+e)$, then $v_2^{(i)}=v_2^{(j)}$, $v_2^TL(G)v_2 = \lambda_2(G)$.

It seems not correct to me since $v_2$ may not be the eigenvector of $L(G)$. For example, the cycle graph with $N=5$. The second eigenvector of $L(G+e)$ is not the same as the second eigenvector of $L(G)$.

Am I correct?   or does anyone know what the author really want to say about this?